# The instruction at "<address>" referenced memory at "<address>". The memory could not be "read."

Tags: c++, c, winapi

A c/c++ app throws that error, how to start to debug (better idea than adding print statements)?

Comment: There is no language called "c/c++" ... Why not just specify which it is? If it's both C and C++ as your tags imply, you could say that.

Comment: What debugger are you most familiar with?  Time to fire it up.

Comment: maybe s/he doesn't know what it's written in.

Comment: to be pedantic, C doesn't "throw" errors.

Comment: A user asks a question, how to start to answer (better idea than answering randomly)?

Answer (score 6):

Is the second address a very small number, like 0x00000001 or 0x00000000? If so, you probably just forgot to initialize a pointer.

In any case, standard debugging tricks apply: start isolating the problem by noticing when it happens and narrowing things down from there.

Comment: Small number: initialized a pointer to NULL, never assigned a proper value. Random number way outside your address space (especially if most or all bytes of the pointer are in the range 0x20-0x7f!): forgot to initialize the pointer, contains bytes from other objects.

Answer (score 2):

The error message suggests that your are developing with Visual Studio. Well, at least that's the only development environment where I've seen this error message in that wording.

If that's the case, you can use the built-in exception debugging to trap the access violation and get the call stack that way.

To do this in the VC++ 2003 I've currently got open, go to Debug->Exceptions, open 'Win32 Exceptions', click on "c0000005 Access Violation" and set "When the exception is thrown" to "Break into debugger".

Comment: I've gotten that error from well-known name-brand software that has crashed, I was under the assumption that the message came from Windows. Always thought it was sad that it reports that the memory could not be "read" or "written".

Comment: Why's it in speech marks too? It's like it is trying to paraphrase or something.

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said, if this is reproducible on your development machine, fire up a debugger and either set breakpoints / step through the code.

However, if this is happening on a customer's machine and a debugger is unavailable, you can get some of the same information (callstack, registers, etc) by using [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634.aspx) and writing the information out to a log file, or doing a minidump.  I suspect a callstack would be the most useful starting place, so you could use one of the StackWalk functions in the handler and write to a log file.  This requires at least either a map file or a set of symbols (PDB) for that build of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Dfficult to suggest anything, without the code. Try using a debugger and setting breakpoints in your code just before you hit the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your development environment, a map file for your program may help

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDB to debug your app: http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/